# Adding new datasets to Open Data Cube using Python API

Tags: python, open-data-cube

I am having trouble indexing GeoTIFF files using the Python API. I have managed to generate a .yml file for my .tif file and would like to now add it to the index. Basically what `datacube dataset add XYZ.yml` would do.

I was able to find

```
dc.index.datasets.add(dataset)
```

I then created the dataset:

```
yml = yaml.safe_load(ymlfile) # ymlfile is the corresponding XYZ.yml
dataset=datacube.model.Dataset(???,cfg)
```

but I can't seem to figure out what the DatasetType should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "Dataset Type" is a [Product Definition, as documented here](https://datacube-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ops/product.html).

The simplest way to programmatically get a document indexed is [documented here](https://datacube-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/api/generate/datacube.index.hl.Doc2Dataset.html).

A slightly different example is [captured in code here](https://github.com/opendatacube/odc-tools/blob/develop/apps/dc_tools/odc/apps/dc_tools/s3_to_dc.py).